# how to select one checkbox from a mapped multiple checkboxes React.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I mapped over a list of objects to render table rows. Each table row has and `input` with `type` checkbox.

```
const [ isChecked, setIsChecked ] = useState(false);

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setIsChecked(e.target.checked)
    };

    const tableRow = clonedUsers.map((user, index) => {
        return (
            <tr key={index}>
                <td className='spacer-left' />
                <td className='checkbox'>
                    <div className='pretty p-svg p-curve'>
                        <input type='checkbox' onChange={handleChange} checked={isChecked} />
                        <div className='state p-primary'>
                            <svg className='svg svg-icon' viewBox='0 0 20 20'>
                                <path
                                    d='M7.629,14.566c0.125,0.125,0.291,0.188,0.456,0.188c0.164,0,0.329-0.062,0.456-0.188l8.219-8.221c0.252-0.252,0.252-0.659,0-0.911c-0.252-0.252-0.659-0.252-0.911,0l-7.764,7.763L4.152,9.267c-0.252-0.251-0.66-0.251-0.911,0c-0.252,0.252-0.252,0.66,0,0.911L7.629,14.566z'
                                    style={{ stroke: 'white', fill: 'white' }}
                                />
                            </svg>
                            <label />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td className='team-name'>{user.name}</td>
                <td className='team-lead-name d-none d-xl-flex'>{user.position}</td>
                <td className='team-index  d-none d-md-flex'>{user.email}</td>
                <td className='team-lead-rating'>
                    <Link to='/people-settings'>Edit team</Link>
                </td>
                <td className='team-lead-rating'>
                    <Link to='/people-settings'>Deactivate user</Link>
                </td>
            </tr>
        );
    });
```

When I click on any checkbox, it is marking all of them as checked. What am I doing wrong here? Is there any better way of implementing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to extract the `checkbox` to a separate component or i would say you need to create a separate component to use a local state for it:

```
export default const Checkbox = props => {

    const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(false);

    const handleChange = e => {
       setIsChecked(!isChecked);
    }

    return (
       <input type='checkbox' onChange={handleChange} checked={isChecked} />
    );
}
```

Now you can use this:

```
<div className='pretty p-svg p-curve'>
    <Checkbox />
```

Comment: What if it needs to be a controlled component - like parent would need to keep track of the checkbox states? :)

Comment: That is where props can be used. :)

Answer (score 1):

> What am I doing wrong here?

The problem is there's only **one** state used for **all** checkboxes.

> Is there any better way of implementing this?

You can either use list or object to store the state for each checkbox.

But for quick lookup, I will use object with the following structure:

```
{ [name]: <checkbox value> }
```

```
const [checked, setChecked] = useState({});

const handleChange = (e, name) => {
  setChecked({
    ...checked,
    [name]: e.target.checked
  })
};

<input type='checkbox'
  onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, user.name)}
  checked={checked[user.name]}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd keep the checked ids in state e.g.:

```js
const [checked, setChecked] = useState([]);

const handleChange = id => () => {
  setChecked(prev => {
    if (prev.includes(id)) {
      return prev.filter(x => x !== id);
    } else {
      return [...prev, id];
    }
  });
};
```

Then in my input:

```js
<input
  type='checkbox'
  onChange={handleChange(user.id)}
  checked={checked.includes(user.id)}
/>
```

A cleaner way to write your handler is with `lodash` using `xor`.

```js
import xor from 'lodash/xor';

///
const handleChange = id => () => {
  setChecked(prev => xor(prev, [id]));
};
```